# How to write large text on console?

Tags: facebook, console

Somebody know how to get this effect which Facebook did on console?

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, the question and the answer both appear to be related to programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to read this article: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

there is an example using Chrome:

```js
console.log('%cHelloWorld', 'font-size: 40px; color: green');
```